# codeigniter access HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: codeigniter

After updating PHP from 5.3 to 5.5.9, codeigniter stopped working. The error displayed is `Prompt HTTP ERROR 500`, but after changing `LoadModule php5_module` to `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp53.so` it works again. It just does not work with PHP 5.5.9. Note that `phpinfo.php` works with PHP 5.5.9
in a `.htaccess` context:

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT development

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

thanks your help

Comment: Attempt to make the question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check error log for **500 Internal Server Error**

On Linux, you can see error log using

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```